# I have a div which i want to make it forceibly scroll horizontally

Tags: reactjs, animation

i want to create a div which i want to make it forceibly scroll horizontal when it is seen on the screen . after the entire div is horizontally scrolled it should get back to vertical scrolling page and move on to other divs . basically horizotal div is has more width which is usally hideen but upon scroll need to make it scroll. when horizontal scroll is taking place vertical scroll should be disabled.

live demo :`https://leadpulse-react.vercel.app/` not working can i anyone help me out

here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Home.css";
import logo from "/LeadPulse_Logo.png";
import logo_light from "/LP_LIGHT.png";
import SwitchButton from "./SwitchButton";
import Button from "./Components/Button/Button";
import "./SwitchButton.css";
import Arrow from "/Arrows.png";
import darkArrow from "/darkArrows.png";
import Passion from "/PASSION.png";
import RedArrow from "/REDARROW.svg";
/* import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer"; */

function Home({ state }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  const [ismenu, setIsmenu] = useState(false);
  const scrollHandler = (event) => {
    let myelement = document.getElementById("scrolldiv");
    console.log(event.deltaY);
    myelement?.scrollBy(event.deltaY < 0 ? -300 : 300, 0);
    console.log(myelement?.scrollBy(event.deltaY < 0 ? -300 : 300, 0));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isChecked) {
      state("light");
    } else {
      state("dark");
    }
  }, [isChecked]);
  //write a function to prevent mouse scrolling when menu is open
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ismenu) {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
    }
  }, [ismenu]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="container">
          <nav>
            <SwitchButton idname="Lights" state={setIsChecked} />
            <img src={isChecked ? logo_light : logo} alt="" />
            <SwitchButton idname="Menu" state={setIsmenu} />
          </nav>
        </div>
        {ismenu ? (
          <div className="menu_list">
            <a href="/">
              What We Do <img src={isChecked ? darkArrow : Arrow} alt="" />
            </a>
            <a href="/">
              {" "}
              Insights <img src={isChecked ? darkArrow : Arrow} alt="" />
            </a>
            <a href="/">
              About Us <img src={isChecked ? darkArrow : Arrow} alt="" />
            </a>
            <a href="/">
              Book a Consultation{" "}
              <img src={isChecked ? darkArrow : Arrow} alt="" />
            </a>
          </div>
        ) : null}
        <div className="hero">
          <h1>
            We <span>craft</span> integrated marketing technology solutions &
            digital interfaces that <span>captivate</span> audiences and&nbsp;
            <span>drive </span>
            conversions.
          </h1>
          <Button link={"#"} text={"Learn More"} />
        </div>
        <div className="passion">
          <div className="passion_col">
            <h2>
              This is our <span>passion</span> and where we <span>excel.</span>
            </h2>
            <p>
              Crafting and implementing advanced marketing tech stacks is what
              we do. <span>That’s all we do.</span>
            </p>
            <p>
              Our sole focus is on creating bespoke integrated marketing tech
              stacks which include marketing automation systems, websites to
              mobile marketing applications.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            className="passion_col"
            id="scrolldiv"
            onWheel={(event) => {
              scrollHandler(event);
            }}
          >
            {" "}
            <div
              className="passion_blocks"
              onScroll={(e) => {
                e.stopPropagation();
              }}
            >
              <div className="passion_block">
                <img src={Passion} alt="" />
                <h3>Omni Channel Experience</h3>
                <a href="/">
                  Learn More <img src={RedArrow} alt="" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="passion_block">
                <img src={Passion} alt="" />
                <h3>Omni Channel Experience</h3>
                <a href="/">
                  Learn More <img src={RedArrow} alt="" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="passion_block">
                <img src={Passion} alt="" />
                <h3>Omni Channel Experience</h3>
                <a href="/">
                  Learn More <img src={RedArrow} alt="" />
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="passion_block">
                <img src={Passion} alt="" />
                <h3>Omni Channel Experience</h3>
                <a href="/">
                  Learn More <img src={RedArrow} alt="" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/*   <Footer /> */}
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

i tried stop propogating and didnt work

Comment: Don't do that.  Users will hate it, because the behavior isn't sensible.  If they're scrolling down, they expect it to scroll DOWN.

Comment: but this is what client has requested

Comment: I understand the issue, but part of the responsibility of a professional programmer is to  inform the client when something is a bad idea.